# How can I have a paragraph-like display in css with different children inside a div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I currently have this:
[image: expected]

But I want to achieve this:
[image: actual]

Is there a way to do it by maintaining the same HTML structure?
Here's the example code:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  /* Makes the container an inline block element */
  vertical-align: top;
  /* Aligns the top edge of the container with the top edge of the previous element */
  width: 600px;
}

label {
  background-color: #8ff;
  display: inline-block;
  /* Makes the label element an inline block element */
}

.content-wrapper {
  background-color: #f8f;
  display: flex;
  /* Makes the content-wrapper an inline block element */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* Prevents the content from wrapping to the next line */
  overflow-x: auto;
  /* Allows horizontal scrolling if the content overflows */
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  /* Makes the child elements inline block elements */
  margin-right: 10px;
  /* Add some spacing between the child elements */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <label>Label</label>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried using flex, grid but nothing works, it works with the label inside the div but I'd prefer not to use that approach or use it as very last resouce

Comment: could you explain more I didn't get your question.

Comment: sorry, with the images is easier to understand but SO wouldn't let me post them inline, but Temani's response solved the problem for me, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need a lot of code for this. Simply make the wrapper an inline element.

```css
.container {
  background-color: #f8f;
  width: 600px;
}

label {
  background-color: #8ff; 
}

.content-wrapper {
  display: inline;
}

span {
  margin-right: 10px; /* Add some spacing between the child elements */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <label>Label</label>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a potential way using `display: contents;`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #f8f;
}

label {
  background-color: #8ff;
  display: inline-block;
}

.content-wrapper {
  display: contents;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <label>Label</label>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
    <span>Content</span>
  </div>
</div>
```